# Call a method of the base type

Tags: go

I have a type from a package, of type `[]byte` internally, that I want to alias and only use a couple of its methods and some of my own. The problem I'm having is how to call the underlying  methods?

An example of the issue:

https://play.golang.org/p/IIGket_W7rk

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Some type from package

type original int

func (o *original) Add() {
    i := *o
    i++
    *o = i
}

// alias type with own method
type alias original

func (o *alias) Add() {
    i := *o
    i.Add()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    i := original(2)
    fmt.Println(i)
    i.Add()
    fmt.Println(i)

    o := alias(2)
    fmt.Println(o)
    o.Add()
    fmt.Println(o)

}
```

Comment: This is not an alias. Just convert the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `original.Add` method on a local copy of a variable. Call it on the receiver:

```
type alias original

func (o *alias) Add() {
    (*original)(o).Add()
}
```